# How to test UIInterpolatingMotionEffect in iOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, ios7

How do you test your iOS7 app's behavior with regard to `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` usage in the iOS Simulator?  What can you do to simulate the hardware events to trigger the parallax effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iOS simulator does not, unfortunately, contain the necessary mechanisms to simulate the parallax effect. You'll need to use a physical device to test that part of your app.